# How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, formatting

How can brackets be escaped in using `string.Format`?

For example:

```
String val = "1,2,3"
String.Format(" foo {{0}}", val);
```

This example doesn't throw an exception, but it outputs the string `foo {0}`.

Is there a way to escape the brackets?

Comment: MSDN String Formatting FAQ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608:  
How do I write out a curly bracket in string formats?  
Do escaped curly brackets have any odd behaviors I need to be aware of?  
How can I use string formatting to write out something like "{42.00}"?

Comment: Unfortunately, the above MSDN link is broken. Currently, the correct link seems to be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx (seet the QA section at the bottom, or search for "escape" on the page).

Comment: Came here when looking for a double curly brackets in a raw string. The solution: if you need 2 curly brackets in a string, you have to use 3 dollars, example: $$$"""\n{ "key": "{{value}}" }\n""", meaning that for a variable you would use 3 curly brackets (e.g. {{{variable}}}) . If you need 3 curly brackets in a string, use 4 dollars.

Answer (score 1485, accepted):

For you to output  `foo {1, 2, 3}` you have to do something like:

```
string t = "1, 2, 3";
string v = String.Format(" foo {{{0}}}", t);
```

To output a `{` you use `{{` and to output a `}` you use `}}`.

**Or now, you can also use C# string interpolation like this (a feature available in C# 6.0)**

**Escaping brackets: String interpolation $("")**. It is new feature in C# 6.0.

```
var inVal = "1, 2, 3";
var outVal = $" foo {{{inVal}}}";
// The output will be:  foo {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: "{{" is treated as the escaped bracket character in a format string.

Comment: But if you want to add value formatting to your string specifier you need also to read the answer from Guru Kara below.

Comment: Read the section _Escaping Braces_ in the official documentation [_Composite Formatting_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

Comment: It's also working in new C# 6 string interpolation (`$"a = {{ {a} }}"`)

Comment: More specific on the C# 6 string interpolation way, doubling up on the curly works like so `string v = $" foo {{{t}}}";`.
If you has other characters to escape that's not a curly you can use the $@ combo `string v2 = $@"\foo {{{t}}}\";`

Answer (score 233):

Yes, to output `{` in `string.Format` you have to escape it like this: `{{`

So the following will output `"foo {1,2,3}"`.

```
String val = "1,2,3";
String.Format(" foo {{{0}}}", val);
```

*But* you have to know about a design bug in C# which is that by going on the above logic you would assume this below code will print {24.00}:

```
int i = 24;
string str = String.Format("{{{0:N}}}", i); // Gives '{N}' instead of {24.00}
```

But this prints {N}. This is because the way C# parses escape sequences and format characters. To get the desired value in the above case, you have to use this instead:

```
String.Format("{0}{1:N}{2}", "{", i, "}") // Evaluates to {24.00}
```

#### Reference Articles

- [String.Format gotcha](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/string-format-gottach)
- [String Formatting FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/string-formatting-faq)

Comment: If I ran into that bug, I'd write `string.Format( "{{{0}}}", i.ToString("N") );` which may be more readable to some.

Comment: @Happy It might, but you'd then find yourself specifying the FormatProvider twice, with the risk that you'd specify different ones, or miss one.

Answer (score 84):

Almost there! The escape sequence for a brace is `{{` or `}}` so for your example you would use:

```
string t = "1, 2, 3";
string v = String.Format(" foo {{{0}}}", t);
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use double open brackets and double closing brackets which will only show one bracket on your page.

Answer (score 17):

I came here in search of how to build JSON strings ad-hoc (without serializing a class/object) in C#.  In other words, how to escape braces and quotes while using [Interpolated Strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) and "[verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string)" (double quoted strings with '@' prefix), like...

```
var json = $@"{{""name"":""{name}""}}";
```

Answer (score 16):

Escaping **curly brackets** AND using **string interpolation** makes for an interesting challenge. You need to use *quadruple brackets* to escape the **string interpolation** parsing and `string.format` parsing.

#### Escaping Brackets: String Interpolation $("") and String.Format

```cs
string localVar = "dynamic";
string templateString = $@"<h2>{0}</h2><div>this is my {localVar} template using a {{{{custom tag}}}}</div>";
string result = string.Format(templateString, "String Interpolation");

// OUTPUT: <h2>String Interpolation</h2><div>this is my dynamic template using a {custom tag}</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[TestMethod]
public void BraceEscapingTest()
{
    var result = String.Format("Foo {{0}}", "1,2,3");  //"1,2,3" is not parsed
    Assert.AreEqual("Foo {0}", result);

    result = String.Format("Foo {{{0}}}", "1,2,3");
    Assert.AreEqual("Foo {1,2,3}", result);

    result = String.Format("Foo {0} {{bar}}", "1,2,3");
    Assert.AreEqual("Foo 1,2,3 {bar}", result);

    result = String.Format("{{{0:N}}}", 24); //24 is not parsed, see @Guru Kara answer
    Assert.AreEqual("{N}", result);

    result = String.Format("{0}{1:N}{2}", "{", 24, "}");
    Assert.AreEqual("{24.00}", result);

    result = String.Format("{{{0}}}", 24.ToString("N"));
    Assert.AreEqual("{24.00}", result);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use C# string interpolation like this (feature available in C# 6.0):

```
var value = "1, 2, 3";
var output = $" foo {{{value}}}";
```

Answer (score 3):

**My objective:**

I needed to assign the value `"{CR}{LF}"` to a `string` variable `delimiter`.

**C# code:**

```
string delimiter= "{{CR}}{{LF}}";
```

Note: To escape special characters normally you have to use \. For opening curly bracket `{`, use one extra, like `{{`. For closing curly bracket `}`, use one extra, `}}`.

Answer (score 3):

I want to put my two cents in. For the raw string literals (which start with 3x double quotes), the above answers won't work but you can work the other way around: You can change the number of curly braces to use in the literal by adding `$` at the start. `$$""" """` means you need `{{` to apply a template value. To answer the OP the below will work:

```
var formatted = $$"""foo {{{val}}}""";
```

Output will be :

```
foo {1, 2, 3}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kbLN4W)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like this.
`var outVal = $" foo {"{"}{inVal}{"}"}  ---  {"{"}Also Like This{"}"}"`

Answer (score 0):

**Escaping Brackets: String Interpolation $(""):**

Now, you can also use C# string interpolation like this (feature available in C# 6.0):

```
var inVal = "1, 2, 3";
var outVal = $" foo {{{inVal}}}";
// The output will be:  foo {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: This seems to be a plagiarised version of [Jorge Ferreira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net/91375#91375) and/or [Aarif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net/48081666#48081666) (incl. the spelling mistakes) (original revisions).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to escape `{{Id}}` while I'm in a **string interpolation**

This worked for me:

```
string url = $"/Details/{{{{Id}}}}";
```

output:

```
/Details/{{Id}}
```