# escaping formatting characters in java String.format

Tags: java, string, string.format

This question is pretty much the same as [this .Net question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net) exept for java.

How do you escape the `%1$` characters in a java `String.format`?

THe reason I need to do this is that I'm building up a string that will later have more info inserted into it. I've thought of having one of the args just be `"%1$"` but that doesn't seem to be very elegant?

sorry if this is obvious my java is a tad rusty.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can just double up the %

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the proposal of Draemon, either you can also have a look at [java.text.MessageFormat class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) that has more powerfull formatting abilities than String.format()