# what is wrong in this string?

Tags: c#, string, format

```
string.Format("{Find Name='{0}'}", name)
```

it throws Exception at runtime saying input string was in wrong format. What is wrong in this string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to escape the '{ characters in String.Format:

```
string.Format( "{{Find Name='{0}'}}", name )
```

See the following for more details:

[How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

Curly braces have a special meaning in formatting strings, and thus need to be escaped. Simply double the literal braces from `{` to `{{` and `}` to `}}`:

```
string.Format("{{Find Name='{0}'}}", name)
```

Answer (score 2):

try `string.Format("Find Name='{0}'", name)`

or try `string.Format("{{Find Name='{0}'}}", name)`

Answer (score 1):

it should be "{{ Find Name = {0} }}"

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
string.Format("Find Name='{0}'", name);
```