# How to include parenthesis for AS-IS output in format string

Tags: c#

I want to see, Hello {} in the output, but the following gives compiler errors

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} \{\}", "Hello");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double parenthesis.

Something like

```
string s = String.Format("{0} {{}}", "Hello");
```

First question at

[String Formatting FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using double brackets. See [How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net) for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {{}}", "Hello");
```