# Putting { in verbatim string with C#

Tags: c#, .net, stringtemplate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape brackets in a format string in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)

How do I put `{` or `}` in verbatim string in C#?

```
using System;

class DoFile {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string templateString = @"
        \{{0}\}
        {1}
        {2}
        ";
        Console.WriteLine(templateString, "a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

I get error when I use '{' or '}' in verbatim string, I guess it's because '{' or '}' is used for parameter marking such as `{0}, {1}, {2}`. `\{` doesn't work.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.String.ParseFormatSpecifier (System.String str, System.Int32& ptr, System.Int32& n, System.Int32& width, System.Boolean& left_align, System.String& format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.String.FormatHelper (System.Text.StringBuilder result, IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Can you include the line of code that fails? Looks like you're using a variant of .Format which does treat { specially.

Comment: This is a problem because of using `Format`, not because of using a verbatim string.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just have to escape with double curly brackets..

`{{` or `}}` respectively..

Something like below

```
string.Format("This is a format string for {0} with {{literal brackets}} inside", "test");
```

> This is a format string for test with {literal brackets} inside

Answer (score 8):

You put two like such `{{` or `}}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about putting `{` and `}` in a string, they should not be escaped. Besides, the escape character `\` has no effect in a @ delimited string.

To use literal `{` and `}` in the format for the `String.Format` method, you double them. So, your format string would be:

```
string templateString = @"
    {{{0}}}
    {1}
    {2}
    ";
```