# Escaping String.Format Placeholder

Tags: c#, escaping, string.format

I have the following string

```
"ListId={1CC88B01-E60F-45D1-8B3C-28852574156D}&amp;ID={0}&amp;ContentTypeID=0x01003D458D19EF31D845B3A7727B0F2F8FC8"
```

I would like to use it as such

```
String.Format("ListId={1CC88B01-E60F-45D1-8B3C-28852574156D}&amp;ID={0}&amp;ContentTypeID=0x01003D458D19EF31D845B3A7727B0F2F8FC8", MyValue)

WHERE MyValue would replace ID={0}
```

However this throws a `System.FormatException`. Obviously this is because of the `{1CC88B01-E60F-45D1-8B3C-28852574156D} guid` that uses the `string.format` placeholder value. Now I can simply split the string call `string.format()` as required and concat it back together but is there perhaps some way I can avoid doing that by "escaping" the placeholder value somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape brackets in a format string in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to double the braces:

```
String.Format("ListId={{1CC8...156D}}&amp;ID={0}&amp;...", MyValue)
```

Comment: Whoops. Why didn't I try that? Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Use double {{ or }} characters to escape them.