# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help with the error shown in the title, my code for this is shown below.
The error is appearing on this line:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Code:

```
@model Assignment2.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Address And Payment";
} 



<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <h2>Address And Payment</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Information</legend>

        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment</legend>
        <p>We're running a promotion: all tickets free with the promo code: "FREE"</p>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Promo Code")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("PromoCode")
        </div>
    </fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Assignment2.Models;

namespace Assignment2.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class CheckoutController : Controller
    {
        TicketBookingEntities storeDB = new TicketBookingEntities();
        const string PromoCode = "FREE";

        //
        // GET: /Checkout/AddressAndPayment

        public ActionResult AddressAndPayment()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Checkout/AddressAndPayment
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
        {
            var order = new Order();
            TryUpdateModel(order);

            try
            {
                if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
                {
                    return View(order);
                }

                else
                {
                    order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                    order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

                    //Save Order
                    storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                    storeDB.SaveChanges();

                    //Process the order
                    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                    cart.CreateOrder(order);

                    return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                        new { id = order.OrderId });
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                //Invalid - redisplay with errors
                return View(order);

            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Checkout/Complete
        public ActionResult Complete(int id)
        {
            // Validate customer owns this order
            bool isValid = storeDB.Orders.Any(
                o => o.OrderId == id &&
                o.Username == User.Identity.Name);
            if (isValid)
            {
                return View(id);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Assignment2.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");

            if (recordToDelete != '') {

                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                             $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                             $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                         }

                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
        });

    function handleUpdate() {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);
        // Update the page elements
        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
        }
        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
    }
</script>
<h3>
    <em>Review</em> your cart:
</h3>
<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
</p>
<div id="update-message">
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Production Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Price (each)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th></th>
</tr> 
@foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
{ 
    <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Performance.Title, "Details", "Store", new { id = item.PerformanceId }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
             @item.Performance.Price
        </td>
        <td id="item-count-@item.RecordId">
             @item.Count
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.RecordId">Remove from cart</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td id="cart-total">
            @Model.CartTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +9358943
   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +107
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(String name) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.get_ErrorMessage() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.RequiredAttributeAdapter.GetClientValidationRules() +45
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.<.ctor>b__1(ModelValidator v) +10
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +238
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String name, ModelMetadata metadata) +632
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +807
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates.StringTemplate(HtmlHelper html) +135
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ActionCacheCodeItem.Execute(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1117
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates.ObjectTemplate(HtmlHelper html, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +575
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates.ObjectTemplate(HtmlHelper html) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +714
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1117
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorForModel(HtmlHelper html) +60
   ASP._Page_Views_Checkout_AddressAndPayment_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Assignment2\Assignment2\Assignment2\Views\Checkout\AddressAndPayment.cshtml:19
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +65
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace Assignment2.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "OrderId")]
    public partial class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Address")]
        [StringLength(70)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter City")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter County")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string County { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {Postal Code")]
        [DisplayName("Postal Code")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Country")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Phone Number")]
        [StringLength(24)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
        ErrorMessage = "Email is is not valid.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }


        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you need any other information please let me know, thanks

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: How is your model (`Assignment2.Models.Order`) looks like?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `{` in your `PostalCode`  `RequiredAttribute`'s error message:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {Postal Code")]
```

remove it and it should work.

You got the exception because the framework uses the `ErrorMessage` as a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) and with one unclosed `{` this is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I had just worked it out myself then saw your post, thanks anyway guys :-)

Comment: Next Answer that helped me: How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/a/91375/1390999