# Provide correct arguments to formatting methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I have the following method in my code

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{0}} Text = \"{1}\"", Matrix, Text);
}
```

`Matrix` is a struct and `Text` is a string.

However, Code Analysis gives me following warning for the method:

```
CA2241
Provide correct arguments to formatting methods
Method 'XX.ToString()' calls
'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])'
and does not provide a format item for argument "1".
The provided format string is: '"{{0}} Text = \"{1}\""'
```

For me it seems like the code of `ToString()` is valid. What I am missing?

Comment: What happens when you try to use `Matrix.ToString()`?

Comment: @RyanGates `string Text { get; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-escape-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/91362/299327)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are escaping your curly braces for {0}. Try {{{0}}}.