# Razor and String.Format don't work with special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with Razor and String.Format. I have a parameter as follow:

```
@{
string aktenHeader = Html.Raw(Model.Node.Aktenzeichen + string.Format("{0}" + Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung, (Model.Node.Aktenzeichen != null && Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung != null ? " ./. " : ""))).ToString();    
}
```

and I got the exception : Input string was not in a correct format.

Please help me friends. Thanks

**EDIT**

Model.Node.Aktenzeichen = "Akte"

Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung = "Test ${}"

And I expected aktenHeader = "Schnulli ./. Test ${}"

Comment: What is the value of `Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung`?

Comment: What's the value of `Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung`, and what are you trying to achieve? The code is relatively convoluted, and we've no idea what the data looks like or what you want the result to be.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Andrei: I updated my post. Thanks for quick responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape your curly braces in `Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichnung`.

```
Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung = "Test ${{}}"
```

This question is already be answered i.e. here: [How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-net)

If you cannot change the/replace the braces as needed, then I think the easiest way of doing this is to not use `string.Format()`:

```
@{
   string aktenHeader = Html.Raw(Model.Node.Aktenzeichen + (Model.Node.Aktenzeichen != null && Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung != null ? " ./. " : "") + Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung).ToString();    
}
```

Comment: It might not be possible in OP's case - what if the string comes from DB and is used in several other places as is?

Comment: I would suggest that escaping is the wrong approach here - it simply shouldn't be part of the format string, as far as I can see.

Comment: I would also not replace it within the format, I would replace it in the ViewModel if it's possible. Otherwise I would work without the string.Format(). I've updated my post.

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl: hey thanks, I don't use string.Format() anymore, and I use your second approach, the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you shouldn't really be including `Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung` in your query string at all. You're just trying to concatenate values in the end, so I suspect you can use:

```
@{
    string x = Model.Node.Aktenzeichen != null &&
                   Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung != null ? " ./. " : "";
    string aktenHeader = Html.Raw(Model.Node.Aktenzeichen + x +
                                  Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung).ToString();    
}
```

I've extracted the long expression out as a separate local variable just for clarity.

If you want to use `string.Format`, you can still do so:

```
string aktenHeader = Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                              Model.Node.Aktenzeichen, x,
                              Model.Node.Aktenkurzbezeichung)).ToString();
```

Fundamentally, it's important to be clear about which parts of your data are meant to be used as a string *format*, and which parts are meant to be used as *values*. You were using `Aktenkurzbezeichung` as part of the format when it looks like you wanted it to just be treated as a value.

Comment: Thanks Jon, very concrete answer. I tried your answer, and it worked too. Appreciated.