# how to escape multiple curly brackets in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to escape the first pair of curly brackets but the second pair or the inner pair should not be escaped.

```
string.Format("@Neptune.ShowAlert(\{content:{0}\})", ex.Message);
```

I have tried the above but I get the "Unrecognized escape sequence" error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `{{` and `}}` to escape the braces.