# How to escape double curly bracket in string.Format()

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have already seen from [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-net) that to escape the `{` or `}` char in C# `string.Format()` you use `{{` or `}}`.

But what I need to do is format a string that looks like this:

```
{{tag}}
```

However, when I try to escape the double curly braces like this:

```
string.Format("{{{0}}}", "tag");
```

or this:

```
string.Format("{{{{{0}}}}}", "tag");
```

The output is always this:

```
{tag}
```

A different way I have found that works is:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

output.Append("{{");
output.Append("tag");
output.Append("}}");
```

But it seems silly to have to have all that just to format a string.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your second variant using 5 braces on each side works for me! `string.Format("{{{{{0}}}}}", "tag");` ==> `{{tag}}`

Comment: Your second sample `string.Format("{{{{{0}}}}}", "tag");` works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do this you need 5 braces on either side of the expression

```
Console.WriteLine("{{{{{0}}}}}", "tag");
```

The break down is

- 2 for the first `{`
- 2 for the second `{`
- 1 for the first `{` in `{0}`

Comment: Seems I had it correct the first time, I'm not clear what my issue was.  A rebuild of the solution seemed to help.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

You can use code this way.

```
string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "{{","tag","}}");
```