# Why escape brackets (curly braces) in a format string in .NET is '{{' or '}}" not '\{' or '\}'

Tags: c#, string, formatting, format

There is  a question [how-to-escape-brackets-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-brackets-curly-braces-in-a-format-string-in-net) but There none to describe the reason? why is using `{{` or `}}` not `\{` or `\}`.

eg.    `string s = String.Format("{{ hello to all }}")`;
 why not using `\{` like  string escape in string such as:    `\b\n\t`

**I want to know the deepin reason  or from the language design **

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Format strings are **interpreted during the runtime** (not during compile time)

If **C#** would allow to enter `\{` or `\}` it would be stored in the string as `{` and `}` respectively. The string.Format function then reads this string to decide if a formatting instruction is to be interpreted, e.g. `{0}`. Since the `\{` resulted in `{` character in the string, the **String.Format** function could not decide that this is to be taken as a format instruction or as literal `{`. So, **string.Format** treats `{{` as literal `{`. Analogous `}}` for `}`.

Escaping in C#:

```
- character literal escaping:   e.g. '\'', '\n', '\u20AC' (the Euro € currency sign), '\x9' (equivalent to \t))
- literal string escaping:  e.g. "...\t...\u0040...\U000000041...\x9..."
- verbatim string escaping: e.g. @"...""..."
- string.Format escaping:   e.g. "...{{...}}..."
- keyword escaping: e.g. @if (for if as identifier)
- identifier escaping:  e.g. i\u0064 (for id)
```