# In C#, How to ignore characters in variable while doing string.format

Tags: c#

I have a string variable called reason for failure which contains user added text for instance the following:

({0}) on arm ({1}} (82)  Kits

Now this variable is part of a method where I am using string.format. I need the string.format to not confuse with {0} {1} in the text of the above variable because I am getting the the exception, **Input string was not in correct format**

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net

Comment: can you do this using a single string.Format..?

Comment: Yeah, your outer `string.Format` isn't doing anything at all.

Comment: the outer string.format works fine, the problem is the value of the variable which just needs to be ignored

Comment: What variable needs to be ignored? I'm confused as to what your question is.

Comment: What is the outer String.Format doing, you didnt supply any replacing parameter to it, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure` contains a [format item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). If don't want them to be treated as format items you'll have to escape them with an extra set of braces. For instance: `{0}` becomes `{{0}}` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net?lq=1).

The quick and dirty solution to your problem would be to replace all opening and closing braces by a double brace:

```
"Reason For Failure:"  + serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure.Replace("{","{{").Replace("}","}}") + "<br/>"
```

A better solution would be to do the replacement using a regular expression:

```
public string EscapeCurlyBraces(string value)
{
    string strRegex = @"(\{\d+\})";
    Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
    string strReplace = @"{$1}";

    return myRegex.Replace(value, strReplace);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
"Reason For Failure:"  + EscapeCurlyBraces(serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure) + "<br/>"
```

**Update**
I suggest you ditch the current solution and rewrite it using a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.StringBuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var emailBody = new StringBuilder();
emailBody.Append("<html><body>RSLMS - Service Request is complete<br/>");
emailBody.Append("Service Request initiated by you is Complete <br/>");
emailBody.AppendFormat("Please use the following link to access Run Log Entry <a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a><br/>", RunLogURL, runLogID);
// ommited some lines
emailBody.AppendFormat("Service ID: {0}<br/><br/>", serviceEntry.ID.ToString());
// ommited some lines
emailBody.AppendFormat("Reason For Failure: {0}<br/><br/>", serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure);
emailBody.Append("Thank you <br/> RSLMS Administrator <br/></body></html>");           

message.Body = emailBody.ToString();
```

Comment: Well its a user added text so I am not certain it would always have those characters or what other new characters they would add :).  I could enforce some javascript in the text box which would stop them to add those variables but I have no issues saving this value to the database column. The problem only happens in the method where I am composing an email.  I am trying out your resolution, seems helpful

Comment: Giving this new information your solution is flawed IMHO. If you want to insert user generated text in an HTML mail you certainly need to HTML encode that string. And I hope you're preventing your database from SQL injection too...

Comment: Should I just encode the string before I format the body of the message. I tried that and still the same error]

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the exception, `The input string is not in the correct format` is due to the way you're constructing the string. In your variable you have two closing braces where string.Format expects only one: `on arm ({1}}`.  If you add this variable as a parameter to String.Format as shown in the first example below, it should resolve this issue.

Otherwise, if you are saying that the variable `serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure` contains the characters `{0}` and `{1}`, and that when you place this variable inside a `String.Format`, those characters are being replaced by the `String.Format` arguments, then this is by design, at least the way you're constructing your string.

Instead of inserting your variable in the string using the `+` operator, include it as another parameter to the `String.Format` call. This way, the `{0}` in your variable will be preserved.

```
message.Body = string.Format(
    "<html><body>Request is complete<br/>" + 
    "Service Request initiated by you is Complete<br/>" +
    "Please use the following link to access " +
    "<a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a><br/>" +
    "Reason For Failure: {2}<br/></body></html>",
    RunLogURL, runLogID, serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure);
```

Now, if you want to replace the `{0}` and `{1}` in `serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure` with some other values, you can nest a String.Format inside another:

```
serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure = "10003 Insufficient Liquid Level detected at " +
    "pipettor channel ({0}) on arm ({1}) (82)";
var channelId = 87;
var armId = 42;

message.Body = string.Format(
    "<html><body>Request is complete<br/>" +
    "Service Request initiated by you is Complete<br/>" +
    "Please use the following link to access " +
    "<a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a><br/>" +
    "Reason For Failure: {2}<br/></body></html>",
    RunLogURL, runLogID, 
    String.Format(serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure, channelId, armId));
```

Or you can do it in two operations:

```
serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure = "10003 Insufficient Liquid Level detected at " +
    "pipettor channel ({0}) on arm ({1}) (82)";

var channelId = 87;
var armId = 42;

var reasonForFailure = String.Format(serviceEntry.ReasonForFailure, channelId, armId);

message.Body = string.Format(
    "<html><body>Request is complete<br/>" +
    "Service Request initiated by you is Complete<br/>" +
    "Please use the following link to access " +
    "<a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a><br/>" +
    "Reason For Failure: {2}<br/></body></html>",
    RunLogURL, runLogID, reasonForFailure);
```

Comment: No the characters are not being replaced in this string. My intent is to leave the value of this variable as is and not replace with anything.  I am getting the exception, Input string was not in correct format

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think the first example above will solve that issue for you, then. Your variable has two closing braces where `String.Format` expects only one.

Comment: Notice I had to 'fix' your input string in my second and third examples (where I did a string.format on the variable value).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two String.Format, you didnt provide parameter for the external , lets say you have x and y for the external Format, this is what you need to do. You need to do double curly braces for those you want to escape from the inner format as in :

```
 var reasonForFailure = "({{0}}) on arm ({{1}}) (82) Kits should still have 50 tests left after run, but it seems like the instrument is not able to pipette anymore from the kits.";
            var message = string.Format(string.Format(
                                    "<html><body>Request is complete<br/>" +
                                    "Service Request initiated by you is Complete" + " <br/> " +
                                    "Please use the following link to access <a href=\"{0}{1}\">{0}{1}</a> <br/>" +
                                    "Reason For Failure:  " + reasonForFailure+"<br/>" +
                                    "</body></html>", RunLogURL, runLogID),x,y);
```