# C# text formatting bug with braces

Tags: c#, formatting, console-application

Why doesn't this code work correctly? Do do I misunderstand something?

```
System.Console.WriteLine("{{{0:c}}}", 12323.09m);
```

Real output:

> {c}

Expected output:

> {$12,323.09}

Comment: why do you need the additional `{}`  around the currency amount

Comment: Amazingly, this time it actually is a C# bug! See this answer specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15085178/369

Comment: `var currFormat = string.Format("{0:c}", 12323.09m);` yeilds `$12,323.09`

Comment: @MethodMan, that's not the required output.

Comment: I know that's why I asked if he needed `{ }` around the output other wise what @VincentUgenti has will suffice

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `{{{0:c}}}` is parsed as `{{` `{` ... `}}` `}`, and not as `{{` `{` ... `}` `}}`.

Try

```
System.Console.WriteLine("{{{0:c}{1}", 12323.09m, '}');
```

Or see a similar sample in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see **Escaping Braces**):

```
int value = 6324;
string output = string.Format("{0}{1:D}{2}", 
                              "{", value, "}");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`System.Console.WriteLine("{" + String.Format("{0:C}", 12323.09) + "}");`

Comment: This works, but doesn't actually answer the question as to why OP's code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I guess you have greater expertise in decoding broken English than I do.

Comment: I guess so. There's only a couple of tense errors in a single sentence. "Why doesn't this code work correctly?" is the obvious "decoding".