# FormatException when passing DateTime.toString() to AppendFormat C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to do the following:

```
 var policyBuilder = new StringBuilder();    

 var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToString("s") + "Z";

 policyBuilder.AppendFormat("{ \"expiration\": \"{0}\",\n", expiration);
```

However, the last line throws the following exception:

```
 An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
 but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

'expiration' is a string, so why am I getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a `{` character at the start of the output?

Comment: I would guess that you probably _do_ want the `{` character in the output, as it appears you're trying to build up a JSON string using a `StringBuilder`.  There are better ways to do this.

Comment: Yes. I figured out that it works fine if I add another { at the start of the string like this:  policyBuilder.AppendFormat("{{ \"expiration  Why is this?

Comment: @djst: that's explained in the link i've provided in my answer ;)

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to build a string using the json format. I wont be serializing it. Its for doing AWS a3 policy signing. [link]http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-HTTPPOSTExpiration

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the link!

Comment: _"I wont be serializing it"_ Well, you don't serialise the JSON string itself - the idea is you'd build an object that has the properties you want, and serialise _that_.  Even without doing that though, there are things around that let you build up a JSON string without serialising objects that will handle this sort of stuff for you (braces and quoting key names/values etc)

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/91362/447156

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks for the help and for setting that straight.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `{` at the beginning you have to use two:

```
policyBuilder.AppendFormat("{{ \"expiration\": \"{0}\",\n", 10);
```

See: [*Escaping Braces* in Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a
>   format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display
>   a literal opening brace or closing brace. **Specify two opening braces
>   ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{")**, or two
>   closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}"). Braces in a
>   format item are interpreted sequentially in the order they are
>   encountered. Interpreting nested braces is not supported. ....