# String.Format with custom Formatter

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I have a custom string formatter, that I want to use after using the Standard formatter, my custom string formatter uses the `{0:SP}` as its format prefix.

What I am trying to do is get this simple example to work

```
  String.Format("{{0}:SP}" , 1)
```

I am getting an exception:

> base: {System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct
>   format.

What it the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Format("{{{0}:SP}}" , 1)
```

it is annoying but you have to put 2 of them inside
if you want to display `{1:SP}`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net) is the original answer