# What does {{{0}}} on string.Format do?

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

In the namespace `MS.Internal`, there is a class named `NamedObject`.

It has a weird block of code:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  if (_name[0] != '{')
  {
    // lazily add {} around the name, to avoid allocating a string 
    // until it's actually needed
    _name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{{0}}}", _name);
  }

  return _name;
}
```

I'm curious about this comment specifically:

```
    // lazily add {} around the name, to avoid allocating a string 
    // until it's actually needed
    _name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{{0}}}", _name);
```

How is that 'lazy'? What does it do to be lazy?

---

Full class from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/NamedObject.cs,6a3daa330bc0a54b):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//
// <copyright file="NamedObject.cs" company="Microsoft">
//    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright> 
//
// Description: Placeholder object, with a name that appears in the debugger 
// 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Globalization;
using MS.Internal.WindowsBase;

namespace MS.Internal
{
  /// <summary> 
  /// An instance of this class can be used wherever you might otherwise use
  /// "new Object()".  The name will show up in the debugger, instead of 
  /// merely "{object}"
  /// </summary>
  [FriendAccessAllowed]   // Built into Base, also used by Framework.
  internal class NamedObject
  {
    public NamedObject(string name)
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);

      _name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      if (_name[0] != '{')
      {
        // lazily add {} around the name, to avoid allocating a string 
        // until it's actually needed
        _name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{{0}}}", _name);
      }

      return _name;
    }

    string _name;
  }
}

// File provided for Reference Use Only by Microsoft Corporation (c) 2007.
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: It only assigns to _name once if its not already done so

Comment: It is considered as lazy because the curly-bracketed string is not generated until the first call to `ToString()`. You can read *lazy* as *on-demand* here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi oh, thats a sneaky little hack

Comment: @Mafii I know the term "lazy" sound pejorative, but lazy evaluation is not a hack in any way. In fact, whole languages are built around that paradigm. In this case, the implementer of `NamedObject` used encapsulation to guarantee that the object behaves as one would expect, while saving some performance in certain cases.

Comment: @KABoissonneault it was in no way meant pejoratively. I love how amazing lazy evaluation is - but it confuses me more often than not to think of what happens when and why, especially in this case. It is implicitely lazy, and more of a workaround. Its a fine piece of code imo, because it is commendet :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You [escape a curly brace with a curly brace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/91362/335858), i.e. `{{` produces `{`, and `}}` produces `}`.

The `{0}` in the middle is interpreted as usual - i.e. a reference to parameter at index zero.

```
{{ {0} }}
^^ ^^^ ^^
|   |  |
|   |  +--- Closing curly brace
|   +------ Parameter reference
+---------- Opening curly brace
```

The end result is the value of parameter zero enclosed in curly braces:

```
var res = string.Format("{{{0}}}", "hello"); // produces {hello}
```

> How is that 'lazy'?

They call it lazy with respect to this alternative "eager" implementation:

```
internal class NamedObject {
    public NamedObject(string name) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        if (name[0] != '{') {
            // eagerly add {} around the name
            _name = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{{0}}}", name);
        } else {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return _name;
    }
    string _name;
}
```

This implementation adds curly braces right away, even though it has no idea that the name enclosed in curly braces is going to be needed.

Comment: So the string is not being initialized until the contidional in the if is true because the compiler doesnt know if it will be run? (it tricks the compiler?)

Comment: @Mafii I replaced the explanation with a "non-lazy" alternative. It looks like they want to minimize the impact of making `NamedObject` instances in case when nobody is planning to call `ToString`.

Comment: Oh, that's cool. Very good explanation, easy to understand. I didn't even think about that. Pretty badass that they do that (considering its only one string)

Answer (score 15):

> How is that 'lazy'? What does it do to be lazy?

The laziness comes from the `if (_name[0] != '{')` before it.

It only changes the `_name` field when it is requested for the first time.

And like everybody already pointed out, `String.Format("{{{0}}}", _name);` should be read as `"{{ {0} }}"` or `"\{ {0} \}"`. The inner `{0}` is the actual field to substitute with the first argument, the outer `{{` and `}}` are a special notation to get single `{}`

Answer (score 10):

`{{` and `}}` just give you literal `{` and `}`. (Escaped curly braces)

so, if you have `{{{0}}}`, and you give along `foo`, the output will be `{foo}`

Answer (score 6):

```
var value = "value";
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{{{0}}}", value); // will output {value}
```

Comment: I can't see a difference to the code posted by the OP anyway. If he would like to run it, he could simply run it.