# String.format throws incorrect format exception when there is an extra } in the string. What is the best way to resolve this?

Tags: c#, json, string, formatexception

String.format throws incorrect format exception when there is an extra } in the string as shown in the snippet below

```
 var input = "1";
 var data = string.Format(@"{0}}", input);
```

I was able to resolve the issue by adding an extra } as shown below

```
var data = string.Format(@"{0}}}", input);
```

However I need to know if there is any better solution to this issue

Comment: `}` is a special character in the formatting context that needs to be escaped. Do you want a more clean and readable way ?

Comment: @user3185569 When i have a large json within the string the escaping by using an extra } character would make the code ugly .Is there a cleaner way to do it

Comment: You're using `string.Format` to echo out JSON!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net

Comment: I think string interpolation would be cleaner `$"{{{input}}}"`

Comment: @user3185569 if he has access to them depending on his version (and that just save a few keystroke)

Comment: @Sehnsucht But it is cleaner as VS Formats the code and change the color to differentiate `{input}` from `{{` and `}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend using C# 6 String Interpolation feature as it is more readable and maintainable:

```
var data = $"{{{input}}}";
```

When the string grows large, you'll see the benefit of Visual Studio formatting and coloring your string like this:

[image]

Comment: that looks a lot cleaner. Thanks. But one small doubt, does the substitution of parameters result in creation of a new string everytime a substitution is made?

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan The compiler transforms the above into `String.Format` behind the scenes. So this is just a syntactic sugar, nothing different from your approach expect that it is cleaner and more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the intended functionality. From the docs:

> How do I include literal braces ("{" and "}") in the result string?
>   A single opening or closing brace is always interpreted as the beginning or end of a format item. To be interpreted literally, it must be escaped. You escape a brace by adding another brace ("{{" and "}}" instead of "{" and "}"), as in the following method call:

```
result = String.Format("The text has {0} '{{' characters and {1} '}}' characters.", 
             nOpen, nClose);
```