# string format and single quote

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I am using a string format with multiple lines of text and one single quotes is a part of that text. The code is like

```
     string _query = @"{ts '{0}-{1}-{2} 00:00:00'}
                                 ";
              _query = string.Format(_query, DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 25);
```

But the string format return exception as

```
  Input string was not in a correct format.
```

How can we add single quote in a multiline text along with string format

Comment: Use parameterized SQL queries. Don't build queries like the above. Parameterized SQL queries = no SQL injection, and no problems with quotes in your strings.

Comment: Obligatory http://bobby-tables.com link

Comment: And for the love of Pete, please don't use implicit joins. They are outdated for over 25 years now.

Comment: Agreed that the sql might not be optimal. But please help to find out what's wrong with string format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)

Comment: @JibinMathew It's not that "the sql might not be optimal" - it's that the sql is dangerously bad. The risk of SQL injection is a really big risk and the solution is really simple - far too simple to not use. btw, your string.format might is wrong in another way - it will return a single digit for a month 9 out of 12 months. You should use `{0}-{1:00}-{2}` as a format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, please avoid building query using string, instead use Parameterized SQL queries.

Regarding your comment on why string Format fails, its because of presence of curly braces in beginning and end of string.You need to escape it. To escape curly braces use "{{" and "}}".

```
string _query = @"{{ts '{0}-{1}-{2} 00:00:00'}}";
```