# Input string was not in a correct format in IJavasScriptExecutor.ExcuteScript

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

So I want to have filter for spans that have certain text.
The jquery works find in console on chrome, but why when I use excuteScript it bring out **System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format** ?

```
JsExecutor.ExecuteScript(string.Format("$(\"h3:contains('{0}')\").closest(\"div.form-group-container\").find(\"span:contains('{1}')\")" +
                ".filter(function(){return $(this).text().toLowerCase()===\"{1}\";})" +
                ".closest(\"tr\").find(\"input\").click()", loonelementenType, excludedLoonelementen));
```

When debug I notice the `.filter(function(){return $(this).text().toLowerCase()===\"{1}\";})` is the one that brought out **System.FormatException**

Comment: You must escape the curly braces for `string.Format`. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net)
That is the one in `function(){` and the other at the end `;})`.

Comment: @mbd Thanks for making it clear for me. I have overcame that problem with another solution, but this problem surely stuck in my head until now. Thanks again mate!!