SQL Server string issue
This INSERT statement works fine when run in SSMS:
INSERT INTO GenInfo
    (ParameterKey, Value, Description, Secured, BranchID, GroupID)
    SELECT 
        'companyURLStem', 'http://dev-sql2019all/company/rdPage.aspx?rdSecureKey={0}', 
        'Main URL to access company reports', -1, BranchID, 4
    FROM Branch

However, when I try to execute this as a string in C# using EF like this:
dbServices.ApplyChangeToTarget(sql);

I get this error:

Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

The culprit is the {0} in the string. How can I avoid this error?
I'm doing this as part of a programmatic data migration from a source db to a target so I don't have much flexibility to do custom work. I would have thought that the string would have executed exactly as it did in SSMS.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Carl

Plenty of answers to this question already.  One of them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net

I'm guessing ApplyChangeToTarget uses string.Format which is interpreting your {0} value as place to inject a value. If that is correct then Craig's suggestion should let you use actual curly braces in your SQL string.  I would also say that if  ApplyChangeToTarget does use string value injection then you may well be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Craig - Thanks. Your response solved it. I was searching under the wrong keyword

Here's the solution:
foreach (var item in newItems)
{
    //Escape the value here:
    item.Value = item.Value.Replace("{", "{{");
    item.Value = item.Value.Replace("}", "}}");

    string sql = @$"INSERT INTO GenInfo
                   (ParameterKey, Value, Description, Secured, BranchID, GroupID)
                        SELECT '{item.ParameterKey}', '{item.Value}', '{item.Description}', {item.Secured}, BranchID, {item.GroupID}
                        FROM Branch";

    dbServices.ApplyChangeToTarget(sql);
}

